# Why does MVC action take so long to return when the method itself is quick

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, visual-studio

I have a .net MVC action that takes 2000ms to complete.
The 2000ms is recorded in the IE Dev tools Network tab, Glimpse and when I use a HttpModule to time the difference between the context_BeginRequest and context_EndRequest.

However, when I record the timings of the action method itself, so from the first line of code in the action to the last line, the time is only 300ms.
My last line of code generates the View, then I log the time and then I return the View - so it seems that even the View generation is within the 300ms:

```
var view = View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
LogMethodTime("HomeController.Index", stopwatch);
return view;
```

I have logged the time when the relevant Controller methods have completed - and they show that the time from the Constructor to the EndExecute only takes 534ms:

```
14:40:26,554 [13] INFO - Constructor
14:40:26,561 [13] INFO - OnAuthentication
14:40:26,608 [13] INFO - OnAuthentication
14:40:26,988 [13] INFO - OnActionExecuted
14:40:27,024 [13] INFO - OnResultExecuted
14:40:27,044 [13] INFO - EndExecuteCore
14:40:27,088 [13] INFO - EndExecute
```

What else in the asp.net pipeline could be swallowing 1700ms please?

I'm running this locally through IISExpress.

Comment: For a MVC action you can see the time to render the view, bringing data time and wire time using Glimpse. I saw that you specified something about Glimpse here. What is, for example, the wire time for your action?

Comment: `var view = View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");` does not "generate the view".  It returns a *"a class that is used to render a view"* - ie when the `ExecuteResult` is called.   So it could be the view rendering that is taking the time.  (ie the view rendering is deferred to a point in time after the controller has returned the `ViewResult`)

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the details above to reflect your suggestion about ExecuteResult. So onResultExecuted would have included that. Still the constructor logging do not account for 1500ms

Comment: I think you may well be dealing with .NET/runtime overhead, or perhaps even network latency issues. Can you duplicate the timing behavior when the code is executed from other boxes?

Comment: I'm running this locally through IISExpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to save 500ms by setting the following in the web.config:

```
<compilation debug="false"
```

Also, by adding more Trace statements, it has highlighted that the bulk of the time occurs between the Application_BeginRequest and the Controller constructor - so I have created a new question to ask that specific detail.

[Time taken between Application_BeginRequest and MVC Controller constructor is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301056/time-taken-between-application-beginrequest-and-mvc-controller-constructor-is-to)

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the Network tab of most browser's development tools don't provide granular reporting of all that's going on--particularly when your web server allows the browser to keep connections alive to transfer all the data needed.  Hint, anything designed for production use does.  To that end, what you are seeing are the following:

- The page itself (as you measured should take ~500ms or less)
- CSS stylesheets from the same server
- JavaScript files from the same server
- Images from the same server

Modern browsers would rather keep the one connection open and request all the resources from the same host (server) at once.  This adds a lot of hidden cost to the connection.  The network tab doesn't always break down the individual network time for the bundle of resources.

To see a better indication of how much time is spent for just the MVC page to return (fully transformed) then you will want to use a tool like [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/).