# Time taken between Application_BeginRequest and MVC Controller constructor is too long

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an MVC page request that takes 1200ms between Application_BeginRequest  and Application_EndRequest.

The bulk of this time is between the Application_BeginRequest and the constructor of the MVC controller - 900ms.

I am using Unity as the dependency injector and EF. The controller has 12 repositorys passed in on the constructor.

```
07:26:40,260 - context_BeginRequest
07:26:40,260 - Application_BeginRequest
07:26:41,180 - Constructor
07:26:41,180 - OnAuthentication
07:26:41,196 - OnAuthentication
07:26:41,321 - OnActionExecuted
07:26:41,352 - OnResultExecuted
07:26:41,352 - EndExecuteCore
07:26:41,352 - EndExecute
07:26:41,399 - Application_EndRequest
```

Comment: I would question my use have twelve repositories referenced from a since controller.  Are most of the methods using all of those repositories every time, or can you pare that down?

Comment: You are probably doing too much during object graph construction. One of the constructors of the components in graph that you're constructing might do initialization (like calling the database). Injection constructors however, [should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

Comment: Show your controller constructor

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using http://structuremap.github.io/ .. it is more faster and has more features. if you are not using the 12 respos in your first call, you can get object later easily when you need it

```
Factory.GetInstance(passedInType)
```